# express - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk

Hello I tried everything but the following very simple code gives me the "Can't set headers after they are sent" error, I've been working on this for days you're input is highly appreciated.

```
  app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
      var emailpassed = req.body.email

      var shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-256', 'TEXT')
      shaObj.update('zzzz' + req.body.password)
      var hash = shaObj.getHash('HEX')

      var params = {
        TableName: 'passengers',
        IndexName: 'emailpass',
        ProjectionExpression: 'password',
        KeyConditionExpression: '#yr = :yyyy',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          '#yr': 'email'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':yyyy': emailpassed
        }
      }

      docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('No such user found.1')

        } else {
          data.Items.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.password != hash) {
              console.log('Incorrect password.1')
            } else {

              var payload = {id: item.pid, password: hash}
              var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'sa')

              if (token) {
                return res.json({token: token})

              }
            }

          })
          console.log('daaakey')

        }
      })
  return;
  }
  )
```

Comment: Did you check the length of `data.Items`? Make sure the length of `date.Items` is not more than 1.

Comment: @Prakesh sharma Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `res.json()` inside a `.forEach()` loop which means you can call it more than once any time `data.Items.length` is more than `1` and some other conditions are met.  Remember that when you do `return res.json()`, the `return` is returning from the `.forEach()` callback and thus the `.forEach()` loop continues to run and the callback an be called again.  The error you are seeing is caused by attempting to send more than one response to a given request which is not permitted.

You need to restructure your code flow such that your either your `.forEach()` loop gathers input (often in an array) and then sends one response containing all the data after the loop is done or if you only intend to send a response on the first token found, then you probably want to switch to a regular `for` loop so you can break out of the loop after you send the response (to avoid sending another one) with a `return` or `break`.  It is not clear from your code which of these scenarios is your likely intention (sending only the first data or accumulating all the data and sending it all).

Comment: Hmm I thought return will break out of the for loop, not true I guess?

Comment: @Leonardo - Look at the code carefully.  The `return` is inside the callback function so it just returns from the callback.  `.forEach()` loops provide no flow control options at all so they are only advised when you always intend to run the full iteration.  A plain `for` loop may be a slight bit more typing, but it gives you lots of flow control options since you can `break` or `return` out of the loop at any time.

Comment: @Leonardo - If this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.